# Group By Map Key and find sum of count field - Mongodb 3.6.9

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document in below structure.

```
[{
        "_id": 0001,
        "data": {
            "status": {
                "COMPLETED": [{
                        "count": 1.0,
                        "assignee": "ABC"
                    }, {
                        "count": 1.0,
                        "assignee": "DEF"
                    }
                ],
                "OPEN": [{
                        "count": 5.0,
                        "assignee": "XYZ"
                    }, {
                        "count": 5.0,
                        "assignee": "PQR"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "assignee": {
                "User1": [{
                        "count": 1.0,
                        "status": "OPEN"
                    }
                ],
                "User2": [{
                        "count": 5.0,
                        "status": "COMPLETED"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "_id": 0002,
        "data": {
            "status": {
                "COMPLETED": [{
                        "count": 10.0,
                        "assignee": "AAA"
                    }, {
                        "count": 10.0,
                        "assignee": "BBB"
                    }
                ],
                "OPEN": [{
                        "count": 50.0,
                        "assignee": "CCC"
                    }, {
                        "count": 50.0,
                        "assignee": "DDD"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "assignee": {
                "User1": [{
                        "count": 10.0,
                        "status": "OPEN"
                    }
                ],
                "User2": [{
                        "count": 15.0,
                        "status": "COMPLETED"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How do we find the total count when grouped by each field.
For example -

```
group by "status" should give result as;  
   => COMPLETED = 22,   OPEN = 110

group by "assignee" should give result as;  
   => User1 = 11 ,  User2 = 20
```

we can simplify the doc by moving "status" and "assignee" out of "data" if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to group by keys you need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to turn them into values of an array. You can also use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) along with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) to count per `status` and then use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) in order to $group them globally:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: {
            obj: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$data.status" },
                    in: {
                        k: "$$this.k",
                        count: { $sum: "$$this.v.count" }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    },
    { $unwind: "$obj" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$obj.k",
            count: { "$sum": "$obj.count" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B5gjMICU2OZ)

Comment: Answer looks good @mickl as always. How about the performance of this one on larger collections due to multiple unwind. Could you help me to understand?

Comment: @Gibbs well there's no alternative approach I can think of since we need to globally group based on nested array's fields

Comment: Thanks @mickl ! first unwind stage { $unwind: "$data.status" } is not required I feel.
Performance is a concern here as there are 5M records in database!

Comment: @Boat you're right, I think it's better to use a different approach with $map - see my modified answer

Comment: Thanks @mickl . The original document is from an aggregated collection.Do you have any suggestion to change the the structure of that document to improve ?

Comment: @Boat just verify if you can avoid having grouping keys as field names (to avoid using $objectToArray)